# showing widgets below ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am creating an application which requires 3 ListViews side-by-side and some data below the ListViews.

I have created a `HorizontalScrollView` in which I have created a TableLayout. It shows like this:

[image: example layout]

However, now I want to add some more widgets like a TextView and some Buttons below the Table.

I tried putting a ScrollView with the HorizontalScrollView but that is problematic as only the ListView will get scrolled and the Buttons below the table won't show. So what are my options of doing this?

Comment: Do you want the buttons on the bottom to always show? or the user needs to scroll in order to see them?

Comment: I want the user to see them once he scrolls down.

Comment: Are there separate buttons for each ListView? or are these the same buttons for all of them together?

Comment: the buttons are not for the ListViews. They are separate from the TableLayout. They provide some different functionality not related to the ListViews.

Comment: I would reconsider this layout because both the ListViews have a vertical scroll and your entire page has vertical scroll. This is very confusing towards your users. Make the buttons always visible and not scrollable

Comment: My entire page does not have a vertical scroll as of now. This is exactly what the source of my confusion is.